# Java Criteria API - Join with embedded id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I've created an application using the Java Criteria API to implement a lazy data model and it works, but i'm trying to reduce the JDBC statements by making a join query. The problem is that one of the entities has an embedded id. You can see the entities definitions below:

Message entitity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Message.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM Message m")
public class Message implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "\"Id_Msg\"")
  private long id_Msg;


  // bi-directional many-to-one association to Recipients
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "message")
  private List<Recipients> recipients;
```

Recipients entity:

```
 @Entity 
    @Table(name="RECIPIENTS")
    @NamedQuery(name="Recipients.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM Recipients m")
    public class Recipients implements Serializable {
        @EmbeddedId
        private RecipientsPK id;

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to Message
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @MapsId(value = "id_Msg")
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "`Id_Msg`", referencedColumnName = "`Id_Msg`", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            })
        private Message message;
```

Recipients PK class:

```
    @Embeddable
public class RecipientsPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="\"Id_Msg\"", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private long id_Msg;

    @Column(name="\"Receiver\"")
    private String receiver;
```

This is how far i've gone by trying to join Message with Recipients entities, but i'm stacked with because of the embedded id:

```
   CriteriaQuery<Message> q = cb.createQuery(Message.class);


  Metamodel m = entityManager.getMetamodel();
  EntityType<Message> Message_ = m.entity(Message.class);
  Root<Message> message = q.from(Message.class);

  Join<Message, Recipients> mess = (Join<Message, Recipients>) message.join(Message_.getSingularAttribute("id_Msg"));
  q.select(message);
```

The above code generates an: org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.BasicPathUsageException: Cannot join to attribute of basic type  (at the join line)

Comment: joining can only be done on a relation ... "Message_.recipients" perhaps